# how to find the location of chrome User Data folder from the omnibar?

Tags: google-chrome

If I want someone to tell me the location of their Google Chrome User Data folder, is there a line they can paste in the omnibar to find out?
In Firefox, I can type about:cache and it lists the location. But in Chrome it lists the content of the cache, not the location of the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I find the location of chrome User Data folder from the omnibar?

Type `chrome://version/` into the omnibar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the link you're looking for is [chrome://version/](http://chrome://version/). This will list a lot of information including the current profile path on the local system.